# In HTML is that a good practice to use both Inline and External stylesheet ?

Tags: html, css

As the following code contains both inline and external stylesheet, is it a good practice to use it ? As a front end developer, I have to clarify this.

Here is my code
    Example :

```
 <!--HTML--> 

  <body>
   <div class="test1" style="width:800px">
     <p>TEST MESSAGE </p>
   </div>
  </body>

 <!--CSS-->

 style.css <!--external stylesheet-->

 .test1{
          color:#555;
          font-size:14px;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always preferred to use all of CSS in external stylesheet to avoid confusion. There would be conflicts if there are CSS in internal as well as external stylesheet.